# Sort content of views with drag and drop

Tags: 8, views

I use Drupal 8, but I can not figure out how to sort views with drag and drop.
The client needs to sort the items of the views in a very personal way.

Do you know some way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Draggable Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/draggableviews) module might be what you need. There is a version of the module for Drupal 8.

According to the module description,

> DraggableViews makes rows of a view "draggable" which means that they
>   can be rearranged by Drag'n'Drop.

I tried the following instructions in the [documentation page](https://www.drupal.org/node/283498) on a vanilla Drupal 8.2.6 installation, and it worked fine (see screenshot below).

> 1. Activate the module and navigate to the edit-page of an existing
>      view.
> 2. Now go to the Format section and choose Table.
> 3. Make sure you have the "Content: Title" field, place it as your first field.
> 4. Add the field "Draggableviews: Content" at the Fields section, place it after the "Content: Title" field.Make sure not to check
>      "Exclude from display"; if you do the view will permit drag and drop
>      but the changes will not be saved.
> 5. Add "DraggableViews: Weight" at the Sort criteria section and place it as the first Sort criteria. Save the view and you're done.

[image]

Comment: I've already tried it, but it does not let me assign a view with drag and drop as order criteria, in version 7 if you can, but in 8 only lets you sort by weight.

Comment: @FenDev - Sounds a little bit like a bug doesn't it? When draggable views ain't draggable.

Comment: @FenDev - I have just tried it with success and edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @dinopmi - In point 5 of your answer, when I make the view order interface I choose in the order criterion it only allows me to derive by weight, but in version 7 of drupal lets order a view by a view with Draggable View.
I have already commented before that I only left by weight, but that is not functional when you create an interface to sort items from a view

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Entityqueue? 
It is a drag and drop interface, in which you insert nodes and sort them.

You can then use the nodequeue as a relation, and sort criteria in views...

https://www.drupal.org/project/entityqueue

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create two set of views (lets say list view and order view) and they both should be sorted by draggableviews:weight. The order list view should be displayed as a table and should have draggableviews:content as one of its fields. See attached example.

Once this is setup, you can go back to list view and click on draggableviews:weight and select the newly created order view as sort order.

Let me know how you go.

STEP 1:
[image]
STEP 2:
[image]
STEP 3:
[image]

Comment: In drupal 8 the option "Display sort as" does not appear in configure sort criterion.

Comment: @FenDev - Then this sounds like a bug you should report on drupal.org.

Comment: The question is clearly about Drupal 8. Why post Drupal 7 solution?

Answer (score -1):

Refer this link, it may help. 
https://www.drupal.org/node/2824325

Comment: @sarika-They have the same problem as me, they have not yet found the solution